# How to get table with AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get data from database and display it in the browser, so

this is my `index.html`:

```
 <button id="getAllGroups" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Groups</button>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <th>Group Id</th>
            <th>Group name</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

These scripts I connected above :

```
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/getGroups.js"></script>
```

Here my get method in RestController :

```
  @GetMapping("/checkGroups")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllGroups() {
    ServiceResponse<List<Group>> response = new ServiceResponse<>("success", groupService.getAll());
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And this my `js` :

```
GET: $(document).ready(
function () {

    // GET REQUEST
    $("#getAllGroups").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ajaxGet();
    });

    // DO GET
    function ajaxGet() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "checkGroups",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.status == "success") {
                     var custList = "";
                    $.each(result.data,
                        function (i, group) {

                            var Html = "<tr>"
                            "<td>" + group.groupId + "</td>"
                            "<td>" + group.groupName + "</td>"
                            "</tr>";
                            $('#tbody').append(Html);
                        });
                    console.log("Success: ", result);
                } else {
                    console.log("Fail: ", result);
                }
            },
    }
})
```

Entity `Group` :

```
@Entity
@ToString
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "groups", schema = "public")
public class Group {
@Id
@Column(name="group_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int groupId;
@NotNull
@Size(min = 4,message = "Group name should consist of 4 symbols!")
@Size(max = 4)
@Column(name="group_name")
private String groupName;
}
```

When I click on `Groups` button on `index.html` where `id="getAllGroups"`, nothing happens but when I try to print only data from database, not in the table format, everything works fine, so, I suppose that trouble in `Ajax`..

Comment: Hi ,what does `result` has in it ? Can you show output of that ?

Comment: do you see the API call happening in the browser > Dev tools?. What is your API and UI URL?

Comment: @Swati Result has an array of 10 rows like in my database - I have 10 groups.

Comment: result or result.data? Why don't you put a console.log in the foreach loop and debug the content of group there? BTW. I am not sure but must it not be Group instead of group?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I get 10 groups from the database, I have checked it.
When I click on button `Groups` on `index.html`, I get 10 groups ( checked it with dev browser tools and console.log ) but groups don't appear on the page

Comment: you should concat the var Html lines with a + sign. otherwise this will create a syntax error which you normally should see on the console as well

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Thanks. You helped me.